# android how to debug java.lang.*

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, java

I want debug this code :

```
 DexClassLoader dexClassLoader = new DexClassLoader(apkPath, optDir, null, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
    Class<?> clazz = dexClassLoader.loadClass(className);
```

when I Step into the load Class method; android-studio step into java 1.8.Source and open java1.8 java.lang.ClassLoader; it must open source/android-27/java/lang/ClassLoader.
How to open the correct java code?

Answer (score 0):

To tell you the truth, it's working in correct direction. DexClassLoader inherits BaseDexLoader which inherits java.lang.ClassLoader. neither DexClassLoader nor BaseDexLoader has overridden loadClass method. 
java.lang.ClassLoader is present on android-x.x.x.jar file. if your IDE in debug mode open Java1.8 class loader instead of Android-x.x.x.jar including class loader, it's compeletely  related to your IDE. if you are using IntelliJ Idea or Android Studio go to project structure, then from Project Setting underlying items, select libraries. Choose android-x.x.x.jar dependency. Next, assign right source path.

Change it from java1.8 into android-x.x.x-source.jar.

Comment: hi Mahdi Rajabi 
thanks for you answer, my IDE is android-studio ,I open the Project setting,but can't find the libraries selection.

Comment: I can find dependencies in project setting. but there is no android-x.x.x.jar in list